# Possible combinations of permutations between N variable-size sets without repetition

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, permutations

I am trying to figure out how many possible combinations of items I can have for N sets with variable number of items and how to get those combinations. Let's say I have three sets as follows.

```
S1: {A, B, C}
S2: {A, C}
S3: {B}
```

Then the expected result is:

```
{A, B, C} | {A, C, B} | {B, A, C} | {B, C, A} | {C, A, B} | {C, B, A}
{A, C}    | {A, C}    | {A, C}    | {A, C}    | {A, C}    | {A, C}
{B}       | {B}       | {B}       | {B}       | {B}       | {B}

{A, B, C} | {A, C, B} | {B, A, C} | {B, C, A} | {C, A, B} | {C, B, A}
{C, A}    | {C, A}    | {C, A}    | {C, A}    | {C, A}    | {C, A}    
{B}       | {B}       | {B}       | {B}       | {B}       | {B}
```

I suppose that for each set **S1** through **S3** I have to calculate all possible permutations of its items hence I will end up with three sets (**S1'**, **S2'** and **S3'**) each containing the corresponding permutations (6 for **S1'**, 2 for **S2'** and 1 for **S3'**). Then I would calculate Cartesian product of those sets (**S1' x S2' x S3'**).

Is such an approach correct? And what would be the formula to calculate the number of all possible combinations?

Comment: This is not clear.  In your example, in the second row, why do you exclude the two cases corresponding to $(B,C,A)$ and $(C,B,A)$ for $S_1$?

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: @lulu An hour ago wanted to say the same but thought it is only me who couldn't understand hehe lolol :P

Comment: @lulu Because those two combinations are already available in the first row. Basically the result should be those 10 combinations. I splitted it into two rows just for readability. Please let me know what else is not clear and I will fix it.

Comment: Still not clear.  Why exclude just those two?  What is special about those  two?

Comment: If I did not omit e.g. combination **[{A, B, C}, {A. C}, {B}]** from the second row, it would be twice (see first row) in the result set. I need only unique combinations.

Comment: The question that @lulu is asking is while did you omit $[\{B,C,A\},\{C,A\},\{B\}]$?

Comment: Not following.  Please edit your post to explain (clearly) which permutations are excluded.  The rules should be precise enough to base a program on.  Don't say things like "Basically the result should be..." .

Comment: @burr Oh, I see it. My mistake. I will fix it.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. By mistake I did not include all combinations. Hopefully it is OK now.

Comment: Your approach seems correct to me (after the edits), you just need to calculate the number of permutations for each set and then multiply the permutation counts together.  In this case, you have $(3!)(2!)(1!)=12$.